# accessing array index in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

So i've got a problem in assembly language x86, i have to prompt the user to enter a number 0-6, and will print a day of the week,(0 = sunday, 1 = monday ..etc).how do i go about this problem here the code i have so far.

```
.model small
    .data
    message db "Please enter a number between 0 and 6$"
      sunday    db "Sunday$"
      monday    db "Monday$"
      tuesday   db "Tuesday$"
      wednesday db "Wednesday$"
      thursday  db "Thursday$"
      friday    db "Friday$"
      saturday  db "Saturday$"


  days  dd OFFSET sunday,  OFFSET monday, OFFSET tuesday, OFFSET wednesday, OFFSET thursday, OFFSET friday, OFFSET saturday

    .code
    main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, 0
    mov cx, 7
    L1: 
        mov ah,9
        mov dx,OFFSET message
        int 21h

        mov ah,1
        int 21h



        mov ah,2h
        mov dl, [days + si] 
        sub dl, 30h     
        int 21h 

        inc [si] 

        mov ah, 9 
        mov dx, offset days
        int 21h

        loop L1



        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
        int 20h


    main endp
    end
```

Comment: Create an array with the addresses of the days, and index that. Do not stick all of the days one after another unless you are prepared to search and count the `$` signs (which then won't really be an array, although technically it is) PS: you missed it after thursday ;)

Comment: Not sure why you switched from `$` to `0`, the DOS output routine will expect the `$`. Anyway, now you can put the addresses into an array that you can then index easily.

Comment: @Jester thx for helping am i ready for indexing sorry for all the question, still learning

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. Note that addresses are 2 bytes each, so you will need to scale by 2 and also load 2 bytes. Furthermore, input is text not number, so you will have to adjust for the ascii code. Not sure what you need the loop for.

Comment: To follow up on Jester's comment, that means that "days" should be a series of dw's, not db's. 8088 / 8086 doesn't have a scale addressing mode, so you'll need to increase SI by 2 on each loop. You need to set CX = 7 before doing the loop.

Comment: @rcgldr good catch about the `dw`. However, he doesn't need to loop at all, he is supposed to read the day number from the keyboard.

Comment: @jester i think i may need a loop so 0-6 sunday -saturday if i type in any other number it should display invalid. But i think i can do that part on my own im just trying to get the first part to display 0-6

Comment: @rcgldr thx i wasnt sure if my incrementing was correct so i commented  what i think i should display inc [si + 2]

Comment: You need to subtract the ascii code so you turn the text entered into a number.  You need to double the offset before indexing. The print function is `ah=9` as you already used that, and the address goes into `dx`.

Comment: @Jester can you give me a example of double offset i have been trying to read up on offset

Comment: The offset is simply double (twice) the index. Once you have the index (because you subtracted the ascii code of 0) just add it to itself to double it.

Comment: The offset is what to add to the base address. So the first one is day + 0, the next one is day+2, the next one at day+4, so you have to multiply the user number (after converting it from Ascii) by 2 before using it as an index.

Comment: @rcgldr what if i want the days to go back to back, sunday+0, monday+1,tuesday+2

Comment: Then SI needs to go to 0, 2, 4, 6, ...